# What's wrong with my simple jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can see on jshint what is up.
There seems to be a problem with the .prop registerUserButton.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready");
  $('#registerUserButton').prop("disabled", true);

  $('#reg_passwordConfirm').bind('keyup', function() {
    var Password = $("#reg_password");
    var confirmPassword = $("#reg_passwordConfirm");

    if ((Password == confirmPassword) && (Password > 1) && (confirmPassword == 1)) {
      $('#registerUserButton').prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What does `What's wrong` mean? Does it not work? Any errors?

Comment: Copying your code into [jshint](http://jshint.com/) doesn't reveal anything

Comment: What should `Password > 1` do? I'm assuming your password is not an `integer`

Answer (score 1):

```
var Password = $("#reg_password");
var confirmPassword = $("#reg_passwordConfirm");
```

should be

```
var Password = $("#reg_password").val();
var confirmPassword = $("#reg_passwordConfirm").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Password = $("#reg_password").val();
var confirmPassword = $("#reg_passwordConfirm").val();
(Password.length > 1) && (confirmPassword.length  == 1)
```

that perhaps solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Hello first of all you made some errors in the recuperation of form values, i edited the script a bit + fixed error and added comments

```
$(document).ready(function() {


 console.log("ready");
  $('#registerUserButton').prop("disabled", true);

  $('#reg_passwordConfirm').bind('keyup', function() {
    var Password = $("#reg_password").val(); // you have to add the .val()
    var confirmPassword = $("#reg_passwordConfirm").val(); // you have to add the .val()

if ((Password == confirmPassword) && (Password > 1) && (confirmPassword === 1)) {
  $('#registerUserButton').prop("disabled", false);
}else { //error handling for the password 
var errMsg = "Sorry but the passwords doesnt match.";
$('#registerUserButton').append(errMsg);
$('#registerUserButton').prop("disabled", true); //Making sure button is disabled
}

});
});
```